# UITextField should have only positive number

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I need to validate a `UITextField`. I want only positive integers to be entered in it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Answered a [similar question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12944946/868193)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add UITextFieldDelegate,and add this code to your class

```
#define LEAGELNUM @"0123456789"
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
        NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:LEAGELNUM] invertedSet];
        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs]     componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        BOOL basicTest = [string isEqualToString:filtered];
        return basicTest;
}
```

LEAGELNUM means you can only write these words

Comment: Hey that one's pretty good! Even better than my approach, +1 for you!

Comment: Hey what if I only want to limit one text box but use another to enter text?

Comment: @Wezly you can check whether the textField is the instance you need to limit. use `if(textField == xxx)` or use its tag like `if(textField.tag == xxx.tag)` xxx is your textField instance.

Comment: In case it is not known, `LEAGELNUM` is a mispelling. I think you meant `LEGALNUM`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd set up a [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to retrieve a number from the UITextFields text property. Then get an intValue from the number and check whether it's >= 0.

**Update:**

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:[textField text]];

[formatter release];
```

This should get you going. I'm not on my development machine right now so I can't test run it, maybe you need to do one or two more lines of setup. Please refer to the reference library (I posted the link above) for the available options.

Comment: Could you please put an example(by editing your answer) that how can I use NSFormatter to check if textfield has positive number only?

Comment: Done - Bonny's answer is still better, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Set delegate to your `UITextField` ivar. Set keyboardType property to `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`
Write this code.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{  
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"-"]){  
        return NO;  
    }  

    return YES;  
}
```

Comment: What if the user has not entered a number. What if user has entered ) or -?

Comment: Set keyboardType property of textField to `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`

Comment: Number pad has some special symbols. How to check if user has entered special symbols?

Comment: UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad doesn't have a ) character. as per              if ([string isEqualToString:@"-"])

Comment: Wow, UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad doesn't have anything except numbers :). It will be only positive value.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head:

Convert the string into a integer using `[textField.text intValue]` and check it is positive.
I would do it in the `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method from the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use logic of this answer [Toastor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954382/uitextfield-should-have-only-positive-number#answer-6954438)

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if (string.characters.count == 0) {
        return true
    }
    /// check number is postive
    if (textField == self.txtPay) {
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        let findalString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        let number = formatter.numberFromString(findalString)
        return number?.integerValue > 0
    }

    return true
}
```