# iOS text field, show only letters, numbers and some punctuation on the keyboard

Tags: ios, ios5

In iOS 5 I wish to have a text field for a user's name. It would be good to have a keyboard that displays only letters and numbers (and maybe 1 punctuation character, or maybe just letters). Perhaps characters not allowed to be used could be greyed out.

Is this functionality possible? Or is there a better way to do it?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954382/uitextfield-should-have-only-positive-number/6954599#6954599

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
       shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
       replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

method in `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. If you'll return NO the change will not be accepted thus leaving text as it was before last input. So basically you just need to implement your acceptance logic inside.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom input view (i.e. a custom keyboard) by using the inputView property. More info on the property: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIResponder/inputView