# iPhone development, what UIKeyboard gives out just letters?

Tags: ios

Is there a `UIKeyboard` that gives out just letters and nothing else? I tried out the alphabet one but it gives out numbers.

Comment: Basically a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233581/ios-text-field-show-only-letters-numbers-and-some-punctuation-on-the-keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a letters-only keyboard without subclassing `UIKeyboard` to create your own from scratch; but you can reject characters you don't want using a `UITextFieldDelegate`.

If `string` is anything other than a letter, return `NO` for this function:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

Here is an adaption of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954382/uitextfield-should-have-only-positive-number/6954599#6954599) for your situation:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```